Empirical Power Analysis base on ANOVA
I am to perform empirical analysis on type I error rate. Here I will generate the data base on normal distribution and sample sizes of 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, and 500.
Then I will replicate the data 1000 times and test using one way ANOVA test and find the empirical type I error rate by taking pvalues that are less than 0.05 and divided by 1000.
The parameters of study are sample sizes, 7 distributions (null, alternative 1 up alternative 7), 5 version forms.
Here is the r code for setting up the data and generating data and finding the test base on sample size of 10. The rest of the sample sizes follows the same code as of sample size 10
Parameters
# Sample sizes
sample_sizes <- c(10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 500)

# Versions
versions <- c("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V")

# Distribution for each version and alternative
distributions <- list(
  "Null" = rnorm,
  "Alternative1" = rnorm,
  "Alternative2" = rnorm,
  "Alternative3" = rnorm,
  "Alternative4" = rnorm,
  "Alternative5" = rnorm,
  "Alternative6" = rnorm
)

Function for the Data
# Function to generate Random Data
set.seed(123)
generate_data <- function(n, version, alternative, replication) {
  mean_value <- 100
  sd_value <- 10
  
  if (version == "V" && alternative != "Null") {
    if (alternative == "Alternative1") {
      mean_value <- 111
    } else if (alternative == "Alternative2") {
      mean_value <- 112
    } else if (alternative == "Alternative3") {
      mean_value <- 115
    } else if (alternative %in% c("Alternative4", 
                                  "Alternative5", 
                                  "Alternative6")) {
      sd_value <- 15
      if (alternative != "Alternative4") {
        mean_value <- 112
        if (alternative == "Alternative6") {
          mean_value <- 115
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  data.frame(
    value = rnorm(n, mean_value, sd_value),
    version = version,
    alternative = alternative,
    replication = replication
  )
}

Function to Generate data for each sample size
# Create a data frame with all combinations of versions and alternatives
combinations <- expand.grid(replication = 1:1000, 
                            version = versions, 
                            alternative = names(distributions),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data Generation when n = 10
df10 <- pmap_dfr(combinations, function(replication, version, alternative) {
  generate_data(n = 10, version, alternative, replication)
})
df10$version <- as.factor(df10$version)

One-Way ANOVA Results when n = 10 at various alternatives
# List for each alternative
results <- list()

# We create a for loop for all alternatives
for (alt in names(distributions)) {
  df_alt <- df10[df10$alternative == alt, ]
  anova_results <- list()

  
  # Subset for each replication
  for (i in unique(df_alt$replication)) {
    subset <- df_alt[df_alt$replication == i, ]
    
    
    # one-way ANOVA
    aov_result <- aov(value ~ version, data = subset)
    
    
    # We want only the P-values
    anova_results[[as.character(i)]] <-
      summary(aov_result)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
  }
  
  
  # Getting the results
  anova_results <- unlist(anova_results)
  
  
  # Dataframe
  anova_results_df <- data.frame(
    replication = names(anova_results),
    p_value = unlist(anova_results),
    alternative = alt
  )

  
  # Significant
  anova_results_df$significant <- 
    anova_results_df$p_value < 0.05
  
  
  # Results for each all pvalues
  results[[alt]] <- anova_results_df
}

Results for Empirical Type I Error Rates
type_I_error_rates <- list()

# For loop for all alternatives
for (alt in names(distributions)) {
  anova_results_df <- results[[alt]]
  type_I_error_rate <- sum(anova_results_df$p_value < 0.05)/1000
  type_I_error_rates[[alt]] <- type_I_error_rate
}

# Results
for (alt in names(distributions)) {
  cat("Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for", alt, ":", type_I_error_rates[[alt]], "\n")
}


The results given below:
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Null : 0.059 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative1 : 0.623 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative2 : 0.721 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative3 : 0.908 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative4 : 0.052 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative5 : 0.619 
Empirical Type I error rate when n = 10 for Alternative6 : 0.777

Now I want to calculate power and plot to see the relationship it has with effect sizes and sample sizes. Here the effect sizes should be calculated base on the different means of the alternative distributions. I calculated using this
# Function to calculate effect size (Cohen's f)
calculate_effect_size <- function(Mean, alt_mean, sd) {
  sqrt(((Mean - alt_mean)^2) / sd^2)
}

# Null hypothesis mean and standard deviation
Mean <- 100
null_sd <- 10

# Alternative means
alt_means <- c(100, 111, 112, 115, 100, 112, 115)

# Calculate effect sizes for each alternative
effect_sizes <- sapply(alt_means, calculate_effect_size, Mean=Mean ,sd=null_sd)

Now calculating power and plotting
# Function to calculate power for ANOVA
calculate_power <- function(effect_size, sample_size) {
  # Initialize a vector to store power results
  power <- pwr.anova.test(k = 5, f = effect_size, sig.level = 0.05, n = sample_size)$power
  
  
  return(power)
}

# Calculate power for each combination of effect size and sample size
power_results <- expand.grid(effect_size = effect_sizes,
                             sample_size = sample_sizes)
power_results$power <- mapply(calculate_power,
                              power_results$effect_size,
                              power_results$sample_size)

# Plot using ggplot2 package 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(power_results,aes(x=effect_size,y=power,color=factor(sample_size))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x="Effect Size",y="Power",
         title="Power vs Effect Sizes for Different Sample Sizes") +
    scale_color_discrete(name="Sample Size") +
    theme_grey()

The output of the graph is:

This does not give me a desirable outcome. There is something wrong somewhere and I have been trying to debug it and still no solution. I need help on the graph.
When I use my effect sizes as a sequence from 0 to 1 instead of the calculating on the effect sizes on the alternatives, I do get a desirable outcome. Like if i take effect sizes to be:
effect_sizes <- seq(0.1, 1, by=0.1)

I get the plot like this:

I need help on achieving a desirable graph for power analysis on the effect sizes base on the alternatives means and the sample sizes. At the end, the first graph (which its effect sizes are calculated on the alternative means ) should look like the second graph (calculated base on effect sizes from 0.1 to 1).
